# BASH: Joining 2 CSV files based on common field name

Tags: bash, csv, join, awk, grep

I have 2 CSV files and I need to JOIN them using BASH:

```
file_1.csv columns: 

track_id    
title
song_id 
release 
artist_id   
artist_mbid 
artist_name 
duration    
artist_familiarity  
artist_hotttnesss
year

Sample date in file_1.csv

TRZZZZZ12903D05E3A,Infra Stellar,SOZPUEF12AF72A9F2A,Archives Vol. 2,ARBG8621187FB54842,4279aba0-1bde-40a9-8fb2-c63d165dc554,Delerium,495.22893,0.69652442519,0.498471038842,2001

file_2.csv columns: 

track_id    
sales_date  
sales_count

Sample data in file_2.csv

TRZZZZZ12903D05E3A,2014-06-19,79
```

The relation between the files is that `file_1.track_id = file_2.track_id`.

I want to create a 3rd file `file_3.csv` that will have the following columns:

```
file_2.track_id,file_2.sales_date,file_2.sales_count,file_1.title,file_1.song_id,file_1.release,file_1.artist_id,file_1.artist_mbid,file_1.artist_name,file_1.duration,file_1.artist_familiarity,file_1.artist_hotttnesss,file_1.year
```

I have tried the following methods:

```
join -t',' -1 N -1 N file_2.csv file_1.csv >> file_3.csv
```

and

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]"," > "file_3.csv"}' file_1.csv file_2.csv
```

Although the `file_3.csv` gets created, it is an empty file.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `join` command should do the trick:

```
join --header -t',' -j 1 file_2.csv file_1.csv
```

Just make sure that your CSV files are sorted on the join fields; having
`track_id` as the first field in each file makes this easy.

You should use test data in both files and when you're satisfied that the command is doing what you want, you can run it against actual data and redirect its output to `file_3.csv`.

Answer (score 3):

Join should work as long as the files are sorted. Try:

```
join -t, <(sort -t, -k1 file_2.csv) <(sort -t, -k1 file_1.csv) > file3.csv
```

Comment: Does this work even when the number of table rows are not the same - i.e. one table has more rows than the other?

Answer (score 1):

With awk

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=substr($0,length($1)+2);next} ($1 in a){print $0","a[$1]}' file_1.csv file_2.csv > file_3.csv
```

file_3.csv contents:

```
TRZZZZZ12903D05E3A,2014-06-19,79,Infra Stellar,SOZPUEF12AF72A9F2A,Archives Vol. 2,ARBG8621187FB54842,4279aba0-1bde-40a9-8fb2-c63d165dc554,Delerium,495.22893,0.69652442519,0.498471038842,2001
```

Comment: How would you retain the column headers with this method?

Comment: @Doug, In this example headers will be retained because in both files the header of the first column is `track_id`. Therefore they match and the header line will be printed, just like any other lines with matching first columns.